# JuMP constraint macro changes type of previously declared variable

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I have a simple math prog that I am trying to solve:

```
m = Model(solver=MosekSolver())
@variable(m, x[1:8] >= 0)
@objective(m,Min,sum(x))
@constraint(m,A*x .== given)
@constraint(m, x, sum(x)==1)

status = solve(m)

println("x = ", getvalue(x))
```

A is some matrix with type `Array{Float64,2`

The line:

> `@constraint(m, x, sum(x)==1))`

Changes the type of `x` from `Array{JuMP.Variable,1}` to `JuMP.ConstraintRef{JuMP.Model,JuMP.GenericRangeConstraint{JuMP.GenericAffExpr{Float64,JuMP.Variable}}}`.

1. Since `x` has been previously declared as a variable shouldn't the type remain the same? (Furthermore if the above line is executed, everything still works, but, `getvalue` will not due to the change in type.)
2. Is there a way to add the summation constraint without changing the type of `x`

Answer (score 1):

refer to [JuMP documentation](https://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/refexpr.html#constraint-references):

> **Constraint References**
>
> In order to manipulate constraints after creation, it is necessary to
>   maintain a reference. The simplest way to do this is to use the
>   special three-argument named constraint syntax for `@constraint`, which
>   additionally allows you to create groups of constraints indexed by
>   sets analogously to `@variable`

So the way JuMP works is as expected, why not `@constraint(m, anothersymbol, sum(x)==1)`?

Answer (score 0):

make it like so

```
@constraint(m, constr, A*x .== given)

@constraint(m, constr2, sum(x) == 1)
```